# Problem with visual studio for Xamarin.Android project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have build class whickhcalled "toy" for example
I used:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

and wrote in the MainActivity.cs this:

```
 static  List<Toy> MissionList { get; set; }
 MissionList = new List<Mission_it>();
```

and I put values as needed in this list.
After that I used intent:

```
public void OnItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(EditActivity));

        intent.PutExtra("pos", position);

        StartActivity(intent);
}
```

In another class i've been trying to use **MissionList**, like this:

```
Mission_it temp = MainActivity.MissionList[some_int];
```

but somehow, it doesn't work. why?

Comment: When you use this other class, is your MainActivity still alive ? what is the error given by visual studio ?

Comment: it says:
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error CS0122 'MainActivity.MissionList' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: in your "other class" you must declare an Activity. So in your constructor you must pass as an argument the MainActivity.

Comment: Make the list `public`. Also, its a bad idea to have references of another activity. Pass the entire `Toy` as extra to the intent